# Django 3.2 и django-debug-toolbar - дублирующиеся запросы в БД

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь разобраться с оптимизацией Django.
Суть вопроса - есть простейшая модель:

```py
class Countries(models.Model):
    CountryName = models.CharField(max_length=100)  # Название страны
    CountryCode2 = models.CharField(max_length=2)   # 2-х буквенный код страны
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.CountryName
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Страна'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Страны'
```

В админке зарегистрирована так:

```py
@admin.register(Countries)
class CountriesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Поставил django-debug-toolbar для посмотреть, и вижу, что в админке при клике по любой ссылке (`Users`, `Groups`, или моя "Страны") эта штука показывает дублирующиеся запросы:

[image: картинка]

Что делать?